# Auto-resize image to fit the browser

Tags: javascript, html, image, autoresize

I have a site which provides "random" pictures of different dimensions, some if not most pictures happen to not fit the browser, so I'd like to know a way to resize it to fit the browser view without scrolling, so why not the guys of Stack Overflow!

Obviously keeping proportions, I tried https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize/ but didn't work as expected.
So it's a html page with some text, the image in the middle and some other text under it.
All I want is for scrolling to be not able to use since the image should be shrunk enough to do so.

Comment: Are you sure https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize/ does not work? It works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/FHq4y/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need any JavaScript or hacks to achieve that kind of image scaling – simple CSS and HTML will just work fine. (BTW also on iPad and iPhone.)

You can just place your `img` with CSS-attribute `height:100%;` and it will have the height of the father node in the DOM-tree. Make sure, that node (usually a `div`) will be properly positioned in the browser window.

Try something like this:

```
<div style="position:fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; top:0;left 0;">
  <img src='whatever.png' style="height: 100%" />
</div>
```

Check out this page as a demo: [andrehelbig.fotograf.de](https://andrehelbig.fotograf.de). Here the background image will always scale proportionally to fill the whole browser window (don't get irritated by the JS scrolling).

Hope that gives a little help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width:80vw;
  height:80vh;
  background:#ccc;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://minisoft.com.bd/uploads/ourteam/rafiq.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for future googler's, I've written a jQuery plugin which is able to auto-resize images with a lot of options :

https://github.com/GestiXi/image-scale

Answer (score -1):

can you please try this code. Replace image src by your image source.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();
document.getElementById('img_canvas').style.height= h +'px';

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="img_canvas" src="images.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I Have a simple solution.

add class in image, then use jquery to automaticaly resize the image. here it code :

```
<img src="" id="imgFitWindowResize">
```

now use the jquery to initialize auto width when the client resize his browser : here the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  function set_body_width() { // set body height = window height
    var wh = $(window).width();
    $(".imgFitWindowResize").width(wh);
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    set_body_width();
    $(window).bind('resize', function() { set_body_width(); });
  });
</script>
```

I Try this code it's work :)